# Springboot Integration - Accessing headers within a MessageHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm trying to move a file to a specific location based on a header that is present in the flow

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow configureFileFlow(
        @Value("${fileSource}") String sourcePath,
        @Value("${fileTarget}") String targetPath
) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            getDataSource(sourcePath),
            conf -> conf.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(pollerDelay))
    )
            .enrichHeaders(eh -> eh.header("targetPath", targetPath)) //<-- this is the target
            .enrichHeaders(eh -> eh.headerExpression("originalFileName", "payload.getName"))
            .channel("processFile.input")
            .get();
}
```

when processing the file, after all necessary procedures are done, I call a bean the following way

```
.handle(backupFile())
```

which calls

```
@Bean
public MessageHandler backupFile() {
    FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(targetPath));
    handler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE_IF_MODIFIED);
    handler.setExpectReply(false);
    handler.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
    return handler;
}
```

How would one go about setting the `targetPath` dynamically based on what's set in the headers, please? I cannot simply pass it along as a parameter since it's a bean and I'd like to avoid creating more beans just for the sake of retrieving a String. Also using a `@Value` again in the second part of the flow feels redundant, since it is already a part of the message itself, in the headers.

There are multiple types of files that are being processed, each has it's own `IntegrationFlow` source, but this part where it gets "backed up" should be shared among all of them. The `backupFile` bean basically needs to have two informations - the file itself as payload and the information from headers on where to store it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See different constructor:

```
/**
 * Constructor which sets the {@link #destinationDirectoryExpression}.
 * @param destinationDirectoryExpression Must not be null
 * @see #FileWritingMessageHandler(File)
 */
public FileWritingMessageHandler(Expression destinationDirectoryExpression) {
```

So, using similar SpEL expression you have above, you can do something like:

```
new FileWritingMessageHandler(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("headers.targetPath"));
```

Also see `org.springframework.integration.file.dsl.Files.outboundAdapter()` for more high-level Java DSL API over that `FileWritingMessageHandler`.

Comment: Wonderful solution, exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!